# Cannot connect to mssql with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, connection, database-connection

I use node-mssql to connect SQL Server I get this error:

message: 'Server responded with unknown TDS version.',

code: 'ETDS'

OBS: SQL Server 8.00.194  - (MSSQL 2000 service pack 2)

config.js

```
module.exports = {
   config: {
       server: 'ip_server',
       user: 'user',
       password: 'password',
       port: 1433,
       database:'name_database',
       options:{
            tdsVersion: '7_1', // Caso não esteja usando o MSSQL 2000 comente esta linha.
            encrypt: false,
        enableArithAbort: false
        }
   }

}
```

index.js

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const config = require('./config').config;

const poolPromisse = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
.connect()
.then(pool => {
    console.log('Connected to MSSQL')
    return pool
})
.catch (err => console.log('Database Connection Failed', err))

module.exports = {
    sql, poolPromisse
}
```

Comment: SQL Server 2000 RTM is v8.0.194. SQL Server 2000 SP2 is v8.0.532. Both still use TDS 7.1, though. Have you confirmed that your SQL Server is actually listening on tcp/1433? The error message suggests that `tedious` (the transport library used by `mssql`) is connecting to some other type of socket service.

Comment: Windows has service pack 2, SQL Server is version 8.00.194.

Comment: I checked with nmap and the server is listening to tcp/1433

Comment: Do you know of any other tests I can do or any documentation to consult?
obs: I can't migrate the database to a current version

Comment: "I can't migrate the database to a current version" Why not? You should be able to do a full backup of each user database with BACKUP DATABASE and restore the resultant .bak files on a newer version of SQL Server with RESTORE DATABASE.

Comment: thanks for the help, solved the problem using the oledb.js library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/oledb